# NoClassDefFoundError when using java.time on Android

Tags: android, java-8, java-time

My Android app uses a JAR which relies on a few classes from `java.time`, such as `LocalTime`, and therefore requires at least Java 8.

Several sources on the net point out that later versions of Android and the tool chain support Java 8.

I build my app with gradle but do not use (or wish to use) Android Studio. I use version 3.1.4 of the plugin (the latest which is compatible with Gradle 4.4, the version that ships with the latest LTS of Ubuntu, 18.04 as of this writing). Minimum SDK is 14, target is 26. Build tools version is 27.0.3.

The app builds and installs fine, but when it tries to use one of the classes, it crashes with an exception:

> `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/LocalTime;`

Questions:

- Is `java.time` available on Android versions with Java 8 support?
- If so, what is the minimum API version? (I tested on Anbox, which supports API 25.)
- Anything else I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is java.time available on Android versions with Java 8 support?

Yes.

> If so, what is the minimum API version?

`LocalDateTime` is available on API Level 26 and higher, as is noted in [the JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDateTime) (see upper-right corner).

> Anything else I am missing?

You might consider using [a backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) of the Java 8 date/time APIs.

Comment: Thanks! For the record, your link points to an Android-specific backport, which is an adaptation of https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/. I am looking into the latter for the JAR, which needs to be portable.

Comment: @user149408: Sorry, your question was tagged `android` and was discussing an Android problem. You might consider using different dependencies for the different build variants (Android vs. non-Android), for [performance reasons](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP#why-not-use-threetenbp).

Comment: Indeed, I should have pointed out that the dependency needs to be portable. Now that opens up the question how to switch between dependencies, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56910021/different-import-dependencies-for-different-environments