# Different import dependencies for different environments

Tags: java, import

I have a JAR which needs some of the classes provided by the `java.time` package, which are available in Java 8 and up.

However, the JAR also needs to be usable on Android, where `java.time` is only available on API 26 and up (I need to support lower APIs as well).

I could simply use [threetenbp](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), which is most portable and provides a compatible implementation with the same class and member names (it is literally just a matter of providing the JAR and changing the import packages).

However, this is not very efficient, especially on Android, where an [adapted version of threetenbp](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) is recommended instead.

Now this leaves me with at least two different choices of packages to import, depending on the environment I am building for: on JDK use `java.time.*`, on Android use `org.threetenb.bp.*`.

Is there a way I can do this without having to maintain two versions of my classes?

Comment: "I have a JAR" -- I assume that this is a library to be used by multiple clients, some Android and some not. If so, you could use the strategy pattern. Have your API accept an instance of a strategy interface that defines the date/time conversions that you need. Have consumers of your API provide implementations, backed by whatever date/time implementation makes sense. IOW, make your JAR agnostic to the mechanism of the date/time conversion.

Comment: Alternatively, just use the portable threetenbp and do some sort of "warmup" in a background thread to get the initialization out of the way before you need it. On ordinary Java, that won't be necessary, but it might help with Android. Usually, this sort of performance issue crops up with lazy initialization; a proactive background initialization can get that out of the way.